# onblur in html select in UIWebView in iOS 7

Tags: html, uiwebview, ios7, html-select, multiple-choice

I have number of html `<select>` elements in webpages which displaying in the app (in `UIWebView` control). Some of them allow multiple choice. I need to perform action when user change something in the list. For multiple choice I need to perform action after user finish rearranging checkboxes and click on 'done'.

How it was implemented in iOS 6 (and works perfectly there):

```
<select onblur="alert('do something...');">...</select>
<select multiple='multiple' onblur="alert('do something...');">...</select>
```

iOS 7 issue:

```
<select onblur="alert('NOT ALWAYS WORK...');">...</select>
<select multiple='multiple' onblur="alert('NOT ALWAYS WORK...');">...</select>

<select onchange="alert('THIS WORKS');">...</select>
<select multiple='multiple' onchange="alert('WORKS BUT NOT AS EXPECTED');">...</select>
```

`onblur` doesn't work relyable anymore. It works only if there is some other textbox or dropdown below. If it's the only dropdown/textbox on the page, it doesn't fire.

I tried replace `onblur` to `onchange`, it works, but only for single choice. For multiple choice `onchange` fired when user change his selection, not when he finished (by clicking "done").

**Any ideas how to solve this for both single and multiple dropdown lists in iOS 7?**

Maybe I missed something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. If load following HTML in UIWebView in iOS 7 (not Safari), the `onblur` event doesn't work:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=10.0'/>
</head>
<body>
<table style='height:80%'><tr><td>

    <select onblur="alert('blur')" >
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
</td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

The important components: *viewport*, *table* with some *height* defined, *select* inside this table.
If remove table OR remove height style OR remove viewport, then `onblur` works.

I can't explain this effect, but I just remove table height style and it works. Maybe it helps somebody.